# Access Outlook Emails from Azure Powershell

Tags: powershell, azure, outlook, azure-powershell

My requirement is to check if a particular email arrived to my inbox using Azure Powershell. I was able to do this successfully from Windows Powershell using `Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.olDefaultFolders`.

Below is the code used with Windows PowerShell, want to achieve the same from Azure Powershell. Difficulty is to connect to outlook server from Azure Powershell.

```
$currentDate = Get-Date
$olFolders = "Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.olDefaultFolders" -as [Type]
$outlook = new-object -ComObject outlook.application
$namespace = $outlook.GetNamespace("MAPI")
$folder = $namespace.GetDefaultFolder(6).Folders("MySubFolder")
$folder.Items |  ForEach {
    If ($_.subject -match "Server Daily Status") 
    {
        If ($_.ReceivedTime -ne $currentDate)
        {
            Write-Output $_.ReceivedTime
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot accomplish this task using Azure PowerShell.

**Reason:** Azure PowerShell is designed for managing and administering Azure resources from the command line, and for building automation scripts that work against the Azure Resource Manager.

For more details, refer “[Overview of Azure PowerShell](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/azure/overview?view=azurermps-5.3.0)”.